# Angular - How to write HTML logic based on Environments

Tags: angular, angular7

In Angular application, I have to display different tables in html based on Production, QA or Test environments.

I have imported below but not sure how to determine QA or Prod environment.
Can someone please help me to handle this

```
import { environment } from ../../../environments/environment;
```

Expected Behavior:

```
if( environment = 'Production') 
 displaycolumns = 5;
else if( environment = 'QA')
 displaycolumns = 3;
else
 displaycolumns = 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the component/service where you need you check the environemt

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

someFunction(){
   if(environment.production){
      console.log("In Production")
   }
   else{
      console.log("In devlopment")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to `app.module.ts`

```
const APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('Application config');
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

{provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: environment},
```

And inside yours component or service

```
constructor(
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG)
    private readonly _appConfig: Environment
  ) {
  }
```